# Google Gson not allowing '@' in attribute name

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using `com.google.gson` and the annotation `@SerializedName`.
When using `@SerialiazedName("@foo")`, it is throwing an IllegalArgumentException because of `'@'` ([See source code](http://codenav.org/code.html?project=/com/google/code/gson/gson/1.4&path=/Source%20Packages/com.google.gson/JsonFieldNameValidator.java)).

When using JSONLint with `{ "@foo": 1 }` the result is a valid JSON object.

Why Google Gson is throwing an exception in that case? Is `'@'` an invalid char for JSON attributes?

Comment: The answer is in the code you posted. The regex used does not allow a name to start with '@'.

Comment: JSON Objects allow any JSON Strings as member names, so every valid JSON String is allowed and that means any Java string -- even the empty one. I don't understand why Gson tries to validate them at all here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very old version of Gson. We're already on [2.3.1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson). Consider updating.

The following works fine

```
public class GsonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(new Allowed()));
    }    
}

class Allowed {
    @SerializedName("@val")
    private String val = "Hey";
}
```

and prints

```
{"@val":"Hey"}
```

The version you were using didn't support it, for whatever reason.

[See here.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/google-gson/JsonFieldNameValidator/google-gson/WtoyOPv45ds) It was fixed in 1.7.